# question about mysql parameter max_connections

Tags: mysql

1.below is mysql config fule, /db/mysql/app/mysql/my.cnf

we set max_connections=4000

```
[mysqld]

sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES 

[client]
port=3306
socket=/db/mysql/data/mysqltmp/mysql.sock
[mysqld]
basedir=/db/mysql/app/mysql
datadir=/db/mysql/data/mydata
tmpdir=/db/mysql/data/mydata/tmp
bind-address=10.200.212.67
port=3306
wait_timeout=86400
server_id=2
user=mysql
socket=/db/mysql/data/mysqltmp/mysql.sock
skip-name-resolve
lower_case_table_names=1
default-storage-engine=InnoDB
max_heap_table_size=32M
thread_stack = 512K
key_buffer_size=256M
sort_buffer_size=2M
join_buffer_size=2M
innodb_file_per_table=1
innodb_open_files=2048
back_log=1000
max_connections=4000
open_files_limit=65535
table_open_cache=128
log_bin=mysql-bin
binlog_format=MIXED
expire_logs_days=7
log_error=/db/mysql/data/mydata/mysql-error.log
pid-file=/db/mysql/app/mysql/mysql.pid
slow_query_log=1
long_query_time=2
slow_query_log_file=/db/mysql/data/mydata/mysql-slow.log
max_allowed_packet=256M
binlog_cache_size=2M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 8192M
innodb_write_io_threads=4
innodb_read_io_threads=4
innodb_thread_concurrency=0
innodb_purge_threads=1
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2
innodb_log_buffer_size=64M
innodb_log_file_size=512M
innodb_log_files_in_group=3
innodb_lock_wait_timeout=7200
sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES
gtid-mode=ON
enforce_gtid_consistency=1
log-slave-updates=1
```

2.when we do some application ,in rush hours ,

In addition, during the problem period of MySQL, the maximum number of connections is less than 1000, and the db max_connections setting is 4000

and when the connection is to 1000, the application will report timeout 30000ms. so app connet failed ,.

3.the quesiton is   if there are any other hidden restrictions that cause the connection not allowed to more than 1000?

Comment: There is a file descriptor limit per mysql process and each connection is a file descriptor. Having so high a number of connections is usually a sign your queries are slow. I recommend attacking the slow queries.

Comment: 30s usually means a *query* timeout, not a *connection* timeout. Your server probably has too much too do (e.g. too many queries) and cannot finish the queries in time. The number of connections seems to be, in that regard, only relevant as an indicator for how many queries you try to run, but the max connection setting (or some assumed hidden limit) isn't the problem (e.g. if the connection wouldn't run an (expensive) query, it's fine). *Why* your server has too much to do (vs what it can do) is another question. Maybe slow/bad queries, locking conflicts, hardware limits (ram, hdd speed), ...

Comment: thanks danblack/Solarflare, we will focus on bad queries tunning .